# Cómo obtener salida de un programa con QProcess

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy haciendo una GUI para una app de Linux que es en consola, logro ejecutar esa aplicación mediante **QProcess**, pero no logro obtener su salida, solo es visible si mi programa se ejecuta desde una terminal, pero quiero mostrar el progreso en mi programa. ¿Alguna idea de cómo pueda obtenerla y mostrarla?

Frangmento del código:

```
QProcess process;
process.start("youtube-dl");
process.execute("algunos argumentos");
```

(query es una variable de tipo texto que toma un comando generado)

Comment: ¿Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de "query.data()" y nombre_de_la_app ya que la forma de invocarlo depende de esa información?

Comment: query es una cadena de texto standard, quizás por eso al usarla debo llamar a data(), supongo que es cosa de QT (soy nuevo en QT)
y bueno, la app es youtube-dl @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar el método `QProcess::execute`([1](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute), [2](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute-1)) es estático por lo que no nos servira ya que no podremos acceder al objeto QProcess por lo que se debe descartar.

Yendo al problema, los QObjects notifican si hay un cambio a traves de señales, por ejemplo en este caso se debe usar [`readyReadStandardOutput`](http://readyReadStandardOutput) e [`readyReadStandardError`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardError) que notifican si hay información en el canal stdout y stderr, respectivamente por lo que en este cado deben ser usadas junto a los métodos [`readAllStandardOutput()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput) y [`readAllStandardError()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError), respectivamente, ya que ellos retornan esa informacion. Para establecer la ubicación del programa se puede usar el método [`setProgram()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setProgram), y para pasar los argumentos extras se debe usa el método [setArguments()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setArguments).

Considerando lo anterior e implementado la siguiente GUI:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent), process(new QProcess{this}),output(new QPlainTextEdit), input(new QLineEdit), button(new QPushButton)
    {
        output->setReadOnly(true);
        button->setText("Start");
        QGridLayout *lay = new QGridLayout{this};
        lay->addWidget(input);
        lay->addWidget(button, 0, 1);
        lay->addWidget(output, 1, 0, 1, 2);
        process->setProgram("youtube-dl");
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Widget::onClicked);
        connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, this, &Widget::onReadyReadStandardError);
        connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &Widget::readyReadStandardOutput);
        connect(process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), this, &Widget::onFinished);
    }
protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event){
        process->kill();
        QWidget::closeEvent(event);
    }
private Q_SLOTS:
    void onClicked(){
        process->setArguments(input->text().split(" "));
        process->start();
        button->setEnabled(false);
    }
    void onFinished(){
        button->setEnabled(true);
    }
    void onReadyReadStandardError(){
        output->appendPlainText(process->readAllStandardError().constData());
    }
    void readyReadStandardOutput(){
        output->appendPlainText(process->readAllStandardOutput().constData());
    }
private:
    QProcess *process;
    QPlainTextEdit *output;
    QLineEdit *input;
    QPushButton *button;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.resize(640, 480);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, readapté el código a mi aplicación y funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciono esto:

```
QPlainTextEdit *plainTextEdit = new QPlainTextEdit(this);
plainTextEdit->setReadOnly(true);

QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
lineEdit->setClearButtonEnabled(true);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
layout->addWidget(plainTextEdit);
layout->addWidget(lineEdit);
setLayout(layout);

connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=](){ plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(process.readAllStandardOutput()); });
connect(&process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [=](){ plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(process.readAllStandardError()); });
connect(&process, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished), this, &Widget::close);
connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [=](){ process.write(lineEdit->text().toLatin1() + "\n"); lineEdit->clear(); });

process.start("sh");
```

Comment: Si está ejecutando desde un terminal no tiene sentido usar `QLineEdit`ni `QPlainTextEdit` ni tampoco el layout

Comment: connect me resulta últil, pero me da errores en esta parte:
plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(process.readAllStandardOutput());
específicamente en process.readAllStandardOutput()

probé hacer otra cosa y me responde a los errores, pero no a las líneas "normales", supongo que es cosa de youtube-dl

Comment: @eferion la idea es obtener una respuesta sin usar la terminal, pensé en la terminal como solución a corto plazo, aunque creo que un QPlainTextEdit es suficiente.